# MySql left join on first match and keep all of primary table data

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case

I am trying to perform a left join from 2 tables.

Table 1 I need all the rows returned, however in joining table 2 I only want to 'append' the data on the first match if there are numerous matches.

Table 1

| id | month |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | August |
| 01 | September |
| 02 | August |
| 03 | September |

Table 2

| _id | service_date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-09-01 |
| 02 | 2022-09-01 |
| 03 | 2022-09-01 |

End Result

| id | month | service_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | August | 2022-09-01 |
| 01 | September | NULL |
| 02 | August | 2022-09-01 |
| 03 | September | 2022-09-01 |

For now I have a simple left join that matches as needed, I just need to find a way to not left join the data on the second match.

Any other JOINs I have tried limit the the table_1 data.

I have tried to use coalesce but have not idea if that is even the correct tool.

I imagine if I could track how many matches the left join has per criteria I could use a conditional statement to null the join on anything more then the first match.

My Sql:

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_1.month, table_2.service_date
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id = table_1.id
```

I hope my question makes sense and any direction on finding the solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your existing `left join` query, you could use `row_number()` to identify the "first" row per `id`, and then conditional logic:

```
select t1.id, t1.month, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t2.month) = 1 then t2.service_date end service_date
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

`row_number()` ranks records having the same `id` ; you probably want something more stable than an month *as string* as an `order by` column.

Comment: Holy Moly you hit it.  I am not sure why yet, will have to do some research on how the row_number and partition worked together, but it worked!  Thanks so very much.